# Can we enable BOT for entire Microsoft Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Can we enable BOT for entire Microsoft Team. Currently I have to select Manifest.json package for individual teams to make it enable. Is this possible, that instead of adding for each team it will be available to entire users on Microsoft Teams.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bots can be added in either an individual team scope, or for personal use.  Installing an app across multiple teams is not something we support today, but we are investigating.